# Query to return pairs of related rows, but only when both rows exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

**I have the following tables:**

> *sistema_documentos*
>
> [id], [caminho], [idDocType](FK -> sistema_DocType.id)
>
> *sistema_Indexacao*
>
> [id] ,[idDocumento](FK -> sistema_documentos.id) ,[idIndice](FK ->
>   sistema_Indexes) ,[valor]
>
> *sistema_DocType*
>
> [id], [tipoNome](FK -> sistema_DocType.id)
>
> *sistema_DocType_Index*
>
> [id],[idName],[mask],[idTipo](FK -> sistema_DocType.id),[tamanho]

**From this query**:

```
select distinct a.id, b.idIndice, b.valor from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId
where d.docTypeId = 40 
and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '22222' )
```

I get the following result

```
id  idIndice    valor
13  11          11111111
13  12          22222
14  11          11111111
14  12          22222
16  12          22222
```

As you can see, I want all ids with idIndice 11 with value 11111111 and 12 with value 22222

Id 16 has id 12 with value 22222 authough it does not have id 11 with value 11111111 so I don´t want it to be shown.

How can I update my query to obtain the result I want. Hope my question is clear. If it is not just ask and I edit my post. Thanks

Comment: Could you post the sample data that produces the results that you show, and the desired results formatted as a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
WITH TempTable AS 
( 
    select distinct a.id, b.idIndice, b.valor  
    from tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Documentos as a  
        join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_Indexacao as b on a.id = b.idDocumento 
    join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType as c on a.idDocType = c.id
    join tgpwebged.dbo.sistema_DocType_Index as d on c.id = d.docTypeId 
    where d.docTypeId = 40      
        and (b.idIndice = 11 AND b.valor = '11111111' OR b.idIndice = 12 AND b.valor = '22222' ) 
)

SELECT *  
FROM TempTable t1 
WHERE (select count(*)          
       from TempTable t2        
       where t1.id = t2.id AND t1.valor != t2.valor) = 1
```

So... get all the results from your first query where there is at least one result from the table that matches on id, but does not match on valor.  (This assumes you could have duplicate rows with the same valor, but you wouldn't want that.)

Comment: This works perfect ... just did not get this tempTable t2. Where it is created??

Comment: I don't know if it's actually created, or if it's just a syntax to use with the "WITH" command in SQL Server.  I would just read up on the "WITH" command.

Comment: Both t1 and t2 reference the TempTable defined in the WITH statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I took out the tables that didn't have direct bearing on the query, although I named them similarly, and I created a simple schema to replicate the problem. I hope this is clear, and that the connection back to your original query is likewise clear.

```
CREATE TABLE Documentos (ID INT, document varchar(12))
create table Indexacao (AID INT, indice int, valor varchar(12))

insert Documentos(id, document)
values (1, 'test1'),
        (2, 'test2'),
        (3, 'test3')

insert Indexacao (aid, indice, valor)
values (1, 11, '11111111'),
        (1, 12, '22222'),
        (2, 12, '22222')
```

The important part of the code is the INTERSECT - it returns only rows that are in both sets. In my experience this operator is usually more efficient than anything containing an `OR`. In the query below, we are getting only those Indexacao rows whose idDocumentos are in the `INTERSECT` of the two sets of conditions.

```
SELECT Ind.*
FROM Indexacao Ind
JOIN (
    SELECT  D.ID
    FROM    Documentos  D
    JOIN    Indexacao   I
    ON      D.ID = I.AID
    WHERE   I.Indice = 11 AND I.valor = '11111111'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT  D.ID
    FROM    Documentos  D
    JOIN    Indexacao   I
    ON      D.ID = I.AID
    WHERE   I.Indice = 12 AND I.valor = '22222'
    )Doc (ID)
ON  Doc.ID = Ind.AID
```

This assumes that you don't have duplicate Indice, Valor rows for a single idDocumento - if you do, you will need to add a DISTINCT.